# asp.net mvc getting id of button clicked

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 <div id="4591" >
            <input type="text" id="Title1" name="Title1"  value="a" />
            <input type="submit" name="button"  value="Save" /> </div>

<div id="4592" >
            <input type="text" id="Title2" name="Title2"  value="a" />
            <input type="submit" name="button"  value="Save" /> </div>

  <div id="4593" >
            <input type="text" id="Title3" name="Title3"  value="a" />
            <input type="submit" name="button"  value="Save" /> </div>
```

This is the copy paste version of the html source generated by the browser which is making it clear that i am generating the dynamic fields on the page. **name in the textbox is the field in the database**.
After pressing the one of the save buttons how would i send the particular textbox name and value to the controller action to be updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give your submit buttons a different name:

```
<div id="4591">
    <input type="text" id="Title1" name="Title1"  value="a" />
    <input type="submit" name="button4591" value="Save" />
</div>

<div id="4592">
    <input type="text" id="Title2" name="Title2"  value="a" />
    <input type="submit" name="button4592" value="Save" /> 
</div>

<div id="4593">
    <input type="text" id="Title3" name="Title3"  value="a" />
    <input type="submit" name="button4593" value="Save" /> 
</div>
```

And then in your controller action check the request parameters. You will see that a parameter with the name of the clicked button will be passed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string id = Request.Params
        .Cast<string>()
        .Where(p => p.StartsWith("button"))
        .Select(p => p.Substring("button".Length))
        .First();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Very neat idea. +1 for doing this with Linq. Just one question: are both the id and name properties necessary, or would just one suffice?

Comment: @draconis  name is sufficient.

Comment: Beautyfull, clean, this is THE way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If someone just stuck on that problem but using newer version of .net I strongly recommend to give buttons different names and use Request.Form

HTML code:

```
<form asp-controller="yourcontroller" asp-action="youraction" method="post">
        <button name="one" class="btn btn-light">one</button>
        <button name="two" class="btn btn-light">two</button>
        <button name="three" class="btn btn-light">three</button>
</form>
```

and method action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult YourAction()
    {
        var buttonNames = Request.Form.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        //now you can see clicked button name from form
        string buttonName = buttonNames.FirstOrDefault();

        //do your logic...
        
        return View();
    }
```